# Parallel proccessing in R with preprocess function does not work

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a huge code with `for loop` in it which takes hours to run and at the end my PC freezes. To improve my code, I used `foreach` along with parallel processing to reduce the run time. My code is like this:

```
library(doParallel)
cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1) 
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach (i=1:3)%dopar%{
{some R code with i index}
preProc <- preProcess(method="bagImpute", train[, 1:lengthvar])
train[, 1:lengthvar] <- predict(preProc, train[, 1:lengthvar])
test[, 1:lengthvar] <- predict(preProc, test[, 1:lengthvar])
}   
stopCluster(cl)
```

The error I am getting is that `preProc` function (for imputation of missing values) cannot be found. My other concern is that it seems using parallel computing increased the run time.

Thanks in advance for your precious guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.packages` in `foreach` function.

```
    library(doParallel)
    cores=detectCores()
    cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1) 
    registerDoParallel(cl)

    foreach (i=1:3,.packages("caret"))%dopar%{
    {some R code with i index}
    preProc <- preProcess(method="bagImpute", train[, 1:lengthvar])
    train[, 1:lengthvar] <- predict(preProc, train[, 1:lengthvar])
    test[, 1:lengthvar] <- predict(preProc, test[, 1:lengthvar])
    }   
    stopCluster(cl)
```